# Save a var for other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

First of all, sorry about my english. Im trying to make a discord bot so you can do .dejmen "Anything" and then .leermen shows you that anything. The problem is that  i tried to set the variable and then require in the other file but its undefined. So, how do i save it.

```
//dejmen.js

run(msg, { text }) {
    msg.delete();
    var dejamens = text;
    return msg.say('se guardo tu mensaje');
}
};

module.exports = ComandoHablar;

 //leesmens.js

const dejmens = require('./dejmen');
run(msg){
    msg.delete();
    return msg.say(dejmens.dejamens);
}
```

Comment: Where you define the variable `ComandoHablar`

Comment: You have to export it.

Answer (score -1):

You should add your variable `dejamens` to the exported module's object.

dejmen.js

```
var ComandoHablar = {};

run(msg, { text }) {
  msg.delete();
  ComandoHablar.dejamens = text;
  return msg.say('se guardo tu mensaje');
};

module.exports = ComandoHablar;
```

leesmens.js

```
const dejmens = require('./dejmen');

run(msg){
  msg.delete();
  return msg.say(dejmens.dejamens);
}
```

Comment: @AndrewLi how about now

Comment: My guess is that `ComandoHablar` is a class, and `run` is *method* (your code snippets have invalid syntax). Don't just attach a property to a class. Just export `ComandoHablar` under a separate name...